# Google sheets mutually exclusive numerical order random number generator

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Bit of a mouthful that one... I'm currently using the script below to generate a random number between 1 and 200 in cells I6:M6. For my intended purpose this script has two problems (neither of which are major but I would like some "polish".

Problem 1) not-mutually exclusive. This is the biggest issue as each of the five numbers MUST be unique. It isn't particularly likely that they will be repeated, but it is somewhat annoying when it does happen.

Problem 2) I have absolutely no idea how or if its even possible to have these random numbers generated and then placed into I6:M6 in numerical order, I6 being the smallest.

I'm a complete amateur and JavaScript (and any other code) and I've only managed to cobble this together from info I've found elsewhere, but I  have a very vague understanding of how it works.

```
///////////////////////////////////////

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [ {name:"Roll Dice",functionName:"rollDice"} ];
  sheet.addMenu("Script", entries);
};

function rollDice() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1 (New)");
    var cell = sheet.getRange("I6");
  cell.setValue( Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1) );
    var cell = sheet.getRange("J6");
  cell.setValue( Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1) );
    var cell = sheet.getRange("K6");
  cell.setValue( Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1) );
    var cell = sheet.getRange("L6");
  cell.setValue( Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1) );
    var cell = sheet.getRange("M6");
  cell.setValue( Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1) );

};

///////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a sort function into the mainLoop function, should sort numerically now.

```
function myFunction() {
  mainLoop()
}

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

function generateNumber(){
return Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1)
}

function setValue(_val, _address){
   var cell =  sheet.getRange(_address)
   cell.setValue(_val)
}

function generate(){
  var array = []
  while(array.length<5){
    var rand = generateNumber()
    var isUnique = array.indexOf(rand) === -1
    if(isUnique){
      array.push(generateNumber())
    }

  }
  return array
}

function mainLoop(){
    var array = generate()
      array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
    var addresses = ['I6','J6','K6','L6','M6']
    addresses.forEach(function (_address,_index){
        setValue(array[_index],_address)
    })
}
```

Comment: Generating all five numbers first before checking if they're unique is not necessary, nor is using recursion when iteration will do as well...

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with this script too, generates random numbers fine but refuses to put them in numerical order

thanks!

Comment: I made an edit, that should make it so it sorts them in numerical order

Comment: @RaphaelCastro You seem to be missing a `return` in `checkUnique()`...

Comment: Function perfectly now, thanks again. Hope this script can help someone else too

Comment: @RaphaelCastro AKX seems to have voted down my answer as well, even after the OP upvoted it.  I've upvoted your answer in an attempt to offset an otherwise shady move.  Feel free to upvote mine as well for similar reason.

Comment: @MattKing I would love to but I am afraid it might get flagged for 'exchange of upvotes', however I dabble in spreadsheets also so if you added an explanation of your answer in your answer it would certainly be super helpful to me **wink wink**

Comment: @RaphaelCastro Ah. I'm new to SO.  That makes sense that that would be frowned upon.  My apologies.  I'll comment on my own response to explain it a bit more!

Comment: Ahh yes, purely by chance I just realised the unique part of the script was non-functional (rolled 52 on 1st & 2nd). If you've not already, would you mind adding/fixing this function as @AKX pointed out - for the benefit of anyone else coming to this thread? 

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Why a script at all? This simple formula in I6 should do it:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(SORTN(SEQUENCE(200),5,0,RANDARRAY(200),1)))
```

Comment: Maybe i'm not understanding. Happy to expand on the idea if need be :)

Comment: SORTN() is a function that allows you to sort one array by another array and to then take the top [n] results.  In my case i created an array of the numbers 1 to 200 using the SEQUENCE() function.  Then i asked it for the top 5 results when sorted by a RANDARRAY(200).  Which is just 200 random numbers between 0 and 1. Since Rand array is a live function however, this will change everytime the sheet is edited and that may not be the goal in Luke's particular scenario.  It might be helpful to others who stumble on this thread in the future though.

Comment: This is an elegant solution, much better than what I originally had (I tried various RAND functions before turning to scripts), however; you are completely right in suggesting my scenario requires more control - my script runs on a button push and absolutely cannot recalculate on change/minute/hourly.

Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{ name: "Roll Dice", functionName: "rollDice" }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script", entries);
}

function rollDice() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1 (New)");
  var numbers = [];
  while (numbers.length < 5) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 + 1);
    if (numbers.indexOf(number) != -1) {
      numbers.push(number);
    }
  }
  numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  ["I6", "J6", "K6", "L6", "M6"].forEach((addr, index) => {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(addr);
    cell.setValue(numbers[index]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank's for this :) There appears to be a syntax error on 19 which is causing the range to appear in non-numerical order? Unless I need to change something that I haven't...

Thanks again though!

Comment: @LukeFreeman I double-checked and don't see a syntax error...

Comment: @LukeFreeman Also, added `numbers.sort()` to sort the numbers. :)

Comment: @AKX you need to pass a callback function to the .sort() function for it to sort numerically, without a callback it only sorts alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to import [randojs](https://randojs.com)? If so you can get an array of ordered unique random numbers from 1 to 200 easily like this:

```js
var sequence = randoSequence(1, 200).slice(0, 5).sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

console.log(sequence);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

So you could just change your `rollDice()` function to look like this:

```
function rollDice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1 (New)");
  var sequence = randoSequence(1, 200).slice(0, 5).sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  sheet.getRange("I6").setValue(sequence[0]);
  sheet.getRange("J6").setValue(sequence[1]);
  sheet.getRange("K6").setValue(sequence[2]);
  sheet.getRange("L6").setValue(sequence[3]);
  sheet.getRange("M6").setValue(sequence[4]);
}
```